# How to handle memory errors with adjacency matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, cluster-analysis, networkx

I am doing graph clustering with python. The algorithm requires that the data passed from graph `G` should be adjacency-matrix. However, in order to get `adjacency-matrix` as `numpy-array` like this:

```
import networkx as nx
matrix = nx.to_numpy_matrix(G)
```

I get a memory error. The message is `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 2.70 TiB for an array with shape (609627, 609627) and data type float64`

However, my device is new (Lenovo E490), windows 64 bit, memory 8 Gb

Other important information could be:

```
Number of nodes: 609627
Number of edges: 915549
```

### The entire story is as follows:

```
Graphtype = nx.Graph()
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'source','target', edge_attr='weight', create_using=Graphtype)
```

#### Markov Clustering

```
import markov_clustering as mc
import networkx as nx

matrix = nx.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(G) # build the matrix
result = mc.run_mcl(matrix)            # run MCL with default parameters

MemoryError
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix you are trying to create is of size `609627x609627` of float64. With each float64 using 8 bytes of memory, you will need `609627*609627*8~3TB` memory. Well your system has only 8GB and even with added physical memory, 3TB seems too large to operate. Assuming your node ids are integer, you can use `dtype=unit4`(to account for all `609627` nodes) but it still will need over TB of memory which sounds inaccessible. What is it that you are trying to do, seems like you have a sparse matrix and you can probably have another possible approach to your goal. The adjacency matrix (unless compressed) seems hard to achieve.

Maybe you can benefit of something like:

```
to_scipy_sparse_matrix(G, nodelist=None, dtype=None, weight='weight', format='csr')
```

in `networks` package. Or rather use edgelist to calculate whatever you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You said something about edgelists. How can i use them here for the same purpose?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve? instead of having adjacency matrix, you can use edgelist matrix of size 915549*8~8MB data. You have 915549 edges, each including two connecting nodes of 4Bytes. That is significantly smaller than adjacency matrix. If you elaborate more on your final goal, maybe we can find a possible way to it.

Comment: I am not expert in markov clustering but I am pretty convinced it uses some sort of random walk on graph. While the package you use accepts matrix as input, the source code seems pretty short. You might want to search for a package that does MCL from edgelist or even implement it yourself. Probably will not be too long.

Comment: It sounds pretty UNEASY for me hahaha because usually adjacency matrices are created from edgelists. So, if i do the other way around, how can i feed it to MCL? still uneasy to figure this out.

Comment: You could also post a question with relative tags. Someone might have some ideas on how to implement MCL from edgelist or maybe some packages already implemented it. Dealing with big data always needs its tricks and tweaks to work around large data sizes.